When I open the terminal I get this message: "bash: hash: hashing disabled"
I have Omakub setup on my Ubuntu 24.04. I have installed Anaconda.
When I open the terminal I get this message: bash: hash: hashing disabled I do not know how to find what file is triggering this alert. Other answers to this general question on your site reference triggering files, but I do not know how to evaluate that question.

You will need to look for a statement like set +h or set +o hashall in one of the files that is sourced during shell startup


How do I find files that are sourced during shell startup?


You can try PS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' bash -lixc true |& grep -e hashall -e +h

ok.  Thanks.  So, I found the result of that command (presumably the file sourced during shell startup that has '+h'.  But what do I do with that information?

@jdstern then share that information with us, so we can help you decide if it's something that should be kept or changed.

The message "hashing disabled" is displayed by the hash command if hashing has been disabled, typically by using set +h or set +o hashall, but also possibly by invoking bash +h or setting `BASHOPTS.
My inclination would be either:

to find the hash command, and before it insert set -h; or
find the set +r or set +o hashall command and delete it.

However neither is entirely safe, and could potentially break something in your system.
Please start by identifying the files containing those two statements. If there's more than one of each, please note each of them.
Are these your personal files (within your home directory) or are they system files (e.g. in /etc or /usr)?
If they're personal files, do you remember why you installed them and/or edited them to add those lines?
If they're system files, which packages installed them, or did you do so by hand? (For deb systems, dpkg -S /path/to/file will report the package that installed the given path; rpm and yum have something similar but I don't know the specifices.)
If any of these are not obvious to you, please attach the files to this question - remembering to redact any personal info of course.

History control
shopt -s histappend
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
HISTSIZE=32768
HISTFILESIZE="${HISTSIZE}"
Autocompletion
source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
Set complete path
export PATH="./bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/share/omakub/bin:$PATH"
set +h
export OMAKUB_PATH="/home/$USER/.local/share/omakub"

Martin,I copy/pasted the file you asked about.  Are you still available to help me resolve my question? Please let me know,

@jdstern sorry it's not clear from your comment which file contains «set +h», but it if it's part of the Omakub package, that should be reported as a bug to the Omakub developers. (There is basically no good reason to do that to someone's login shell.) Before reporting to them, you should also identify which of your files contains the “hash” command that's the proximate cause for the error.

The Omakub developers' response to your bug report will indicate whether it's safe for you to delete it in your own system.

Not your code, but export OMAKUB_PATH="/home/$USER/.local/share/omakub is wrong; it should be export OMAKUB_PATH="$HOME/.local/share/omakub. Account home directories are not necessarily be in /home, and in some cases must not be in there.

Thank you, Martin Kealey.  I have raised this issue with omakub.  Let's see if we can get a bug fix for it. Thanks for your help.
